# make the div container with profile pictures slide right to left and stop on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to PHP and bootstrap.

How can wrap following code to make it auto rotate and stop with mouse hover over?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 member" style="min-height:256px;">
    <div class="well"'.$boxShadowEffect.'>
        <div class="col-xs-12 nopad text-center">
            <a href="/'.$memberUrl.'">
            <div style="max-height: 212px; min-height: 212px;">
            <img style="max-height: inherit; '.$imageShadowEffect.'" class="img-thumbnail" alt="profile" src="https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-3b0b70b336bbae35853994ce0aa25013-c">
            </div>
            </a>
            <a href="/'.$memberUrl.'">  <h4 class="tmargin bold text-info"  title="name">Profile Name</h4></a>
            <p> Registered User</p>


            <a class="tmargin btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" href="/'.$memberUrl.'">View Full Profile </a>                                                   
        <br>
        </div>      
      <br>
        <div class="clearfix">  </div>                                                                                          
    </div>  
<br>    
</div>
```

Above code is just one example, I have 8 of these which shows something like below when I put them in a div class ="col-md-12"
[image]

How can I make them rotate left to right when there are more then 4? also stop rotating with mouse hover over (may be control button?)

Thanks

Comment: You need to add a carousel plugin. I recommend owlcarousel 2.

Comment: bootstrap has its own carousel.